# How to achieve scrollable grid view exactly like in this photo using flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

[Staggered Grid View](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)  can achieve sizing and everything, but it always starts placing items from the top,
just under app bar. How to achieve to add that text (Found 10 items for example) and then start displaying items in grid view?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `GridView` of the image, you will find a pattern.

On `itemCount:` pass `itemLength+1`. This extra `1` will be help to insert `Text`.

TO build this GridView use `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder`

```dart
 StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return index == 0
              ? Center(child: Text("Item s "))
              : Container(
                  color: index.isEven ? Colors.amber : Colors.deepPurple,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("$index s"),
                );
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
          return index == 0
              ? StaggeredTile.count(1, .3) //For Text
              : StaggeredTile.count(1, 1); // others item
        },
      ),
```

[image]

TO learn more about [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view).

**Pattern draw** sorry for the bad drawing, hope you got the concept now.

[image]

Comment: Excuse me on not being clear enough and for not forming question a little better.
This is actually my first question on Stack Overflow. :) 

Such a clear answer. I had my first experience with staggered grid view last night and I was super tired su I couldn't even read documentation. I had built the same screen without using this package but it's much cleaner and more flexible with staggered grid view.